# Scala flatten a List

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I want to write a function that flattens a List.

```
object Flat {
  def flatten[T](list: List[T]): List[T] = list match {
    case Nil => Nil
    case head :: Nil => List(head)
    case head :: tail => (head match {
      case l: List[T] => flatten(l)
      case i => List(i)
    }) ::: flatten(tail)
  }
}

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    println(Flat.flatten(List(List(1, 1), 2, List(3, List(5, 8)))))
  }
}
```

I don't know why it don't work, it returns `List(1, 1, 2, List(3, List(5, 8)))` but it should be `List(1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8)`.

Can you give me a hint?

Comment: This is a fun as an exercise. For real code, of course, there _is_ a `flatten` method on `List`.

Comment: That wouldn't work in this case. The list here is a `List[Any]` so you'd have to define an implicit conversion from Any => TraversableOnce[_] to call flatten. It must be possible but I doubt it's simpler than this function.

Comment: Take a look at the compiler errors and warnings: they'll give some big clues

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By delete line 4

```
case head :: Nil => List(head)
```

You will get right answer.

Think about the test case

```
List(List(List(1)))
```

With line 4 last element in list will not be processed

Answer (score 33):

You don't need to nest your match statements.  Instead do the matching in place like so:

```
  def flatten(xs: List[Any]): List[Any] = xs match {
    case Nil => Nil
    case (head: List[_]) :: tail => flatten(head) ++ flatten(tail)
    case head :: tail => head :: flatten(tail)
  }
```

Answer (score 16):

My, equivalent to SDJMcHattie's, solution.

```
  def flatten(xs: List[Any]): List[Any] = xs match {
    case List() => List()
    case (y :: ys) :: yss => flatten(y :: ys) ::: flatten(yss)
    case y :: ys => y :: flatten(ys)
  }
```

Comment: How would `(x :: ys) ::: yss` means `if it is a list of elements followed by another list`?  (as `()` means a tuple AFAIK not list)

Comment: @MuhammadHewedy There are no commas, so it's not a tuple - it's just parentheses to force the correct associativity (without them, `y :: ys :: yss` would match the first two elements and rest of the list, not a nested list as desired).

Answer (score 3):

```
  def flatten(ls: List[Any]): List[Any] = ls flatMap {
    case ms: List[_] => flatten(ms)
    case e => List(e)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone does not understand this line of the accepted solution, or did not know that you can annotate a pattern with a type:

```
case (head: List[_]) :: tail => flatten(head) ++ flatten(tail)
```

Then look at an equivalent without the type annotation:

```
case (y :: ys) :: tail => flatten3(y :: ys) ::: flatten3(tail)
case Nil :: tail => flatten3(tail)
```

So, just for better understanding some alternatives:

```
def flatten2(xs: List[Any]): List[Any] = xs match {
  case x :: xs => x match {
    case y :: ys => flatten2(y :: ys) ::: flatten2(xs)
    case Nil => flatten2(xs)
    case _ => x :: flatten2(xs)
  }
  case x => x
}

def flatten3(xs: List[Any]): List[Any] = xs match {
  case Nil => Nil
  case (y :: ys) :: zs => flatten3(y :: ys) ::: flatten3(zs)
  case Nil :: ys => flatten3(ys)
  case y :: ys => y :: flatten3(ys)
}
```

```
val yss = List(List(1,2,3), List(), List(List(1,2,3), List(List(4,5,6))))
flatten2(yss) // res2: List[Any] = List(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) 
flatten3(yss) // res2: List[Any] = List(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

By the way, the second posted answer will do the following, which you probably don't want.

```
val yss = List(List(1,2,3), List(), List(List(1,2,3), List(List(4,5,6))))
flatten(yss) // res1: List[Any] = List(1, 2, 3, List(), 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```