# Scala - Is there any way to convert pattern matching into if / else?

Tags: scala, if-statement, functional-programming, pattern-matching

I unsuccessfully tried to implement the `flatten` function in Scala, but did find this implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13059590/scala-flatten-list):

```
def flatten(xs: List[Any]): List[Any] = xs match {
case Nil => Nil
case (head: List[_]) :: tail => flatten(head) ++ flatten(tail)
case head :: tail => head :: flatten(tail)
}
```

Now, is there any way to write this in terms of `if/else`? I'm trying to wrap my head around pattern matching, and it would help to see an if/else implementation of this pattern matching. I understand that `(head: List[_]) :: tail` means something like "if xs is a list with a head that's also a list and tail", but can't find a way to rewrite this in terms of if/else. Is pattern matching the same as `if/else`, or is it a completely different construct than it? Can all if/else statements be made into pattern matching, and vice versa? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be something like this:

```
 if (xs.isInstanceOf[List]) {
   val lst = xs.asInstanceOf[List]
   if (lst == Nil) {
     Nil
   } else if (lst.head.isInstanceOf[List]) {
      flatten(lst.head.asInstanceOf[List]) ++ flatten(lst.tail)
   } else {
      lst.head :: flatten(lst.tail)
   }
 }
```

Comment: I see, this looks quite messier than pattern matching. Would that be the motivating factor in using pattern matching vs if/else?

Comment: under the hood it will be translated to things like this, so you need to understand what compiler will generate instead of pattern matching. No magic ;)

Also keep in mind that pattern mathching wouldn't catch all the cases for you, like type erasures. It's all about checking instances, and sometimes - translation directly into switch statement if possible.

Comment: Gotcha. This code caused the following errors when I tried compiling it, however: `- type mismatch; found : Unit required: 
  List[Any]
 - type List takes type parameters
 - type mismatch; found : Unit required: 
  List[Any]`

Comment: try to replace `[List]` by `[List[_]]`