# How to flatten List[Any, List[]] in Scala

Tags: scala

```
val xs = List(List(4, List(4, 7)), List(3, List(3, 5)), List(4, List(5, 9))
```

How do I convert that to:

```
List(List(4, 4, 7), List(3, 3, 5), List(4, 5, 9))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala flatten List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13059590/scala-flatten-list)

Comment: That is not flattening. Flattening simply creates a list by decomposing internal lists

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
xs.map(arr => arr.foldLeft(List[Any]())((acc, value) => value match {
    case xs:List[Any] => acc ++ xs
    case x:Any => acc :+ x
}))
```